# Añadir shortcode en todos los posts WordPress ANTES de the_content

Tags: wordpress

Estoy usando un código en mi `functions.php` para añadir automáticamente un `shotcode` en todos los posts de mi blog *WordPress*, el problema está en que necesito que el `shortcode` se muestre **ANTES** del contenido (`the_content`) y no después como sucede ahora.

Este es el código

```js
function my_shortcode_to_a_post( $content ) {
  global $post;
  if( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) return $content;
 
  switch( $post->post_type ) {
    case 'post':
      return $content . '[my_post_shortcode_goes_here]My content[/my_post_shortcode_goes_here]';
    default:
      return $content;
  }
}
 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_shortcode_to_a_post' );
```

Con este código, el `shortcode` se muestra correctamente en todos los posts, pero **DESPUÉS** del contenido.

***Necesito mostrar ese shortcode antes del contenido siempre.***

Quedo atento a vuestra ayuda,

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

La mejor practica es afectar la plantilla directamente, por lo general es el archivo page.php o single.php

y debes de agregar antes de `<?php the title();?>` el shortcode `<?php do_shortcode('[tushortcode][/tushortcode]);?>`